# Multiplayer team queue, depends on ELO

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, socket.io, matchmaking

im doing a project for a client, im totally out of mind how i should do it.

Firstly i will describe it:
On my PHP web app, unique user have ELO, which is like a skill of player. Player can go in Queue system as a team (5players)/ mix/ as alone.

And now how I can match up players to plays against another team depends on his ELO, which language (i though good idea will be a node server, but currently im totally dont know which is better, i will have to learn it so tell me which is the best for it, becouse it doesnt matter for now me tho).

Is there any helpers of it/tutorials or anything bcs i cant get anything in google :(

Im really glad if you will help me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is far too broad. Please see How to ask a Good Question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have a queue of group of players (sized for 1 to 5) with a calculated average of their ELO.
Then, you may have a worker that is constantly looking at this table/collection and that compares average ELOs.
When similar ELOs are found, you can merge the groups until you have 2 groups of 5 people with close ELO.

Node server might be a good choice but you can also do this using Laravel queues (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues).

Hope it helps  :)

Comment: Yea thats it, but how can I  increase the "similar elo" of matching them to a match?

Comment: @mymek, your process must be :
1. pick an incomplete group (less than 5 players) (random or first of the collection). "currentELO" will be the ELO of this group. //
2. look for every group with a size less than 5 - currentSize and where averageELO(ELO of the group) +/- deltaELO(a variable starting from 0) of your currentELO and sort by ABS(averageElo - currentElo) in an indexed array. // 
3. look into this array if a group may be added to your selected group. //

Comment: @mymek, (CONTINUED) ... 
4. increase the deltaELO (the step 2 and 3 should be in a loop) to find more groups if required // 
5. IF group is composed of 5 players, check if their is another 5 players group close to this ELO, ELSE, wait and repeat above process with other players.